# Dot in Kohana 3.2 route

Tags: routes, kohana-3.2

I'm creating dynamic sitemap for my Kohana 3.2 website and I faced with next error. Route doesn't work if I use dot "." in it. Like this(http://localhost/sitemap.xml):

```
Route::set('sitemap', 'sitemap.xml')
->defaults(array(
'controller' => 'static',
'action' => 'sitemap'));
```

In this case everything works fine(http://localhost/sitemap):

```
Route::set('sitemap', 'sitemap')
->defaults(array(
'controller' => 'static',
'action' => 'sitemap'));
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Hi there, did my answer worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you asked

```
Route::set('sitemap', 'sitemap.<format>', array( 'format' => 'xml'))
  ->defaults(array(
     'controller' => 'static',
     'action' => 'sitemap',
  ));
```

This route will allow you to use other "filenames" as action, just separate supported formats with a pipe. eg `'xml|rss|json'` etc

```
Route::set('static', '<action>.<format>', array( 'format' => 'xml'))
  ->defaults(array(
     'controller' => 'static',
     'action' => 'sitemap',
  ));
```